# Symbolic AI in the medical field, specifically in diagnosing a patients condition. Have i understood the concept behind how it works?

Tags: ai-design, symbolic-ai

This scenario should demonstrate just how the system along with the rule works in a medical diagnosis where the symptoms of the patient are evaluated by the system to determine what condition he/she could have.

Just say a patient is suspected to be experiencing anaphylaxis, although the onset of anaphylaxis usually happens within seconds to minutes and an EpiPen is usually on standby, it wouldn't have the need to be diagnosed by a Symbolic AI in the first place, for the sake of argument lets say that it did (hypothetical situation), The rule related to the system would look like this.

If the patient has anaphylaxis AND the patient has a weak and fast-paced pulse AND struggles with abdominal pain the conclusion could be that the patient may be going into anaphylaxic shock.

The process the AI goes through to reach this conclusion is by connecting the dots per se through deductible reasoning and making the logical assumption that since the patient has all the symptoms it's most likely anaphylactic shock. New information could come in the form of a new symptom. This new information would lead the AI to deduce it through a reasoning engine like that of a Bayesian network (it leans toward reasoning with the information that's been presented to it rather than just directly relaying information to what's being asked as a search engine would do). The reasoning process involves the need for human intervention when a phenomenon arises (the new symptom could be ear pain). Since the symptom doesn't correlate to anaphylaxic shock it could potentially need a new system in place since it's most likely a symptom of an earache. Regardless of this, the new information by which the phenomena relate or don't relate in this case and potentially in need of a new system must be hard-coded directly into the system's program, updating the rule. However, If the symptom had been struggling to breathe the current system rules would have been updated to include it, since it is a symptom of anaphylaxic shock. The rule coded in is a preconception, in other words, it's a hard assumption. Ultimately the system should be a flexible one (assumption wise) and the input given results in an accurate decision.

Comment: What is the question here? Seems there is none.

Comment: I'll see if I can clear it up. The question is this the process a Symbolic AI goes through when diagnosing a patient's condition? Have I got all the details correct such as when a new symptom (new information) arises in a patient, say the symptom doesn't correlate to the assumed diagnosis, in this case, anaphylactic shock, does the current system get updated or does it need an entirely new system with a new rule? This is what I'm trying to say. Hope this helps.